# Error converting list to string

Tags: python, string, list, csv

I am trying to specify the position where I would like my data to be written in my output file but I am getting the following error. Could I please be advised on how I might resolve this issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/Upstream and downstream shores.py", line 20, in <module>
    upstream_shore.writerow (line[0] + [upstream_1] + line[1])
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv

file1 = open ('fileA.csv', 'rt', newline ='')
reader = csv.reader(file1)

upstream = open ('fileB.csv', 'wt', newline = '')
upstream_shore = csv.writer(upstream)

downstream = open ('fileC.csv', 'wt', newline = '')
downstream_shore = csv.writer(downstream)

count_upstream = 0
count_downstream = 0

for line in reader:
    downstream = [(int(x) - 2000) for x in line[2]]
    upstream = [(int(y) - 2000) for y in line [1]]
    upstream_1 = str(upstream)
    downstream_1 = str(downstream)
    upstream_shore.writerow (line[0] + [upstream_1] + line[1])
    count_upstream += 1
    downstream_shore.writerow(line[0] + line [2] + [downstream_1])
    count_downstream += 1

 print ('Number of upstream shore counts:', count_upstream)
 print ('Number of downstream shore counts:', count_downstream)

file1.close()
upstream.close()
downstream.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: BTW, the python error was pretty clear. What didn't you understand in the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line:

```
upstream_shore.writerow (line[0] + [upstream_1] + line[1])
```

`line[0]` (and `line[1]`) is a string, not a list.  Python is trying to concatenate a string and a list, but it doesn't know how so it gives you the `TypeError`.  You probably want `[line[0]]` instead so that it's concatenating 2 lists (which is knows how to do)  e.g.:

```
upstream_shore.writerow ([line[0]] + [upstream_1] + [line[1]])
```

<sup>Note, you'll have the same error again 2 lines down.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `line[0]` which is a string with `[upstream_1]` which is a list. You should instead use `[line[0]]` to create a list with just one item.

```
upstream_shore.writerow ([line[0]] + [upstream_1] + [line[1]])
```

Comment: Thanks to both of your answers. I wish I could choose both answers as my final answer.